# Will replacing cracked digitizer screen also fix dead pixels?

Tags: laptop, lcd

My fiance dropped his Toshiba Satellite c55t b5230 laptop, and the touch screen digitizer cracked. A few days later, we noticed a short row of dead pixels, about an inch and a half long, in the middle of the screen.

We had already ordered a new digitizer screen to replace the cracked one, but I'm wondering, is there a chance this will also solve the row of dead pixels on the screen?  Or should I order a new LCD as well, before we even start disassembling?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Pixels are in the LCD, not the digitizer

Comment: Right, I know that.  My thought was that one common 'fix' for dead or stuck pixels (not sure which these are) is to 'massage' the pixel with, say, an eraser tip.  I don't want to try doing that with the current cracked screen. I was wondering if I replaced the digitizer, what the odds are the pixels might come back to life via 'massage' or one of those software programs out there.

Comment: Software can't repair damaged hardware... Just replace the LCD...

Comment: Right, I guess I was hoping these might turn out to be 'stuck' as opposed to dead pixels, and I was trying to avoid spending more money on an lcd screen if it wasn't necessary.  Especially since is a budget laptop to begin with, there's a limit to how much money seems worth spending on repair.

Comment: I have never seen those tricks work, but all you can do is try.

Comment: "Will replacing cracked digitizer screen also fix dead pixels?"  you need to change your title, its misleading after reading your comment.

Answer (score 0):

**Q. Will replacing a cracked digitizer screen also fix dead pixels?**

---

**A. No.**

The digitizer is solely responsible for converting your touch inputs to a digital signal understood by your computer.

Typically, there are three layers involved with capacitive touch screen technology, the highest layer is normally a thin sheet of glass. This is often attached to the digitizer, which, for your machine, looks like this:

[image]

The final part is the LCD panel, which actually displays the image through the digitizer and glass.

[image]

As such, replacing the digitizer will have no effect on the LCD image.

---

**Q. I was wondering if I replaced the digitizer, what the odds are the pixels might come back to life via 'massage' or one of those software programs out there.**

---

**A. Perhaps, but as your screen has taken physical damage, very unlikely.**

There are software utilities that will cycle all pixels on the screen through full colour ranges, which can on occasion resolve the issue. There are also methods of trying to massage the screen to fix the stuck pixels. However, in your scenario where the screen has taken physical damage and an entire row is damaged, it's very unlikely this will be a temporary state with an easy fix. As such, a replacement of the LCD unit is likely your only resolution for this.